# C# method that can optionally be implemented by subclass, without a base method

Tags: c#, syntax

I have Code OCD, so bear with me.

We have a base class with:

```
virtual protected void OnHierarchyInitialized()
{
}
```

Now when someone overrides this method, they almost are to be expected to call the base method:

```
protected override void OnHierarchyInitialized()
{
    base.OnHierarchyInitialized();
}
```

But.. nothing is happening in the base method. Nor will in the future. I just don't want people that subclass need to 'worry' *when* and *if* they need to call the base method.
Plus: this is ugly *fat* in the implementing code, that distracts from the rest of the code that looks like a C# version of the Mona Lisa itself.

Of course I could make it an `abstract` method, but here is the big disadvantage that it *needs* to be implemented. Also screws up my work of art.

**Question**

Is there something in between a virtual and abstract method, that tells the message:

`override me optionally, but there is no base method to call` ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you worry about them calling the base method or not if it does nothing?

Comment: It makes it slightly more confusing to use, because you have to 'think' what might happen in the base method. It goes against my OCD. We're talking perfectionism here!

Comment: So the thing is: I don't want people that subclass it to worry about it.

Comment: Put it in the docs then (XML docs?)

Comment: I think you're basing this off of a "you must always call the base class's method if your override" rule - which doesn't really exist.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but how should the implementer know? He needs to think about what might happen in the base method. Documenting seems the closest answer, was just hoping there was some static typed solution.

Comment: (ps, to be clear: this is not a *huge* problem in my life, just some kind of an OCD perfectionism ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure the only thing you can do is use the built in XML documentation to notify the callers. For example, this is how it would show up to the person overriding your method:

[image: XML Documentation]

Answer (score 1):

There is no keyword in c# to do that. `virtual` is the best there is for this approach.

Just don't worry about if there is an base class implementation or not. The one implementing the derived class shouldn't worry about it.

There is just one question: Does the current implementation totally replace the base class's implementation?

If it does, don't call the base class. If it doesn't: call it.

Comment: That last question is an (in theory unnecessary) question that I try to get rid of for the writers of the subclass. We're talking static typed perfectionism here ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your code looks like this:

```
public void Foo()
{
    // do something

    OnHierarchyInitialized();

    // do something else

}
```

You may want to consider events instead of inheritance:

```
public event EventHandler HierarchyInitialized = delegate { };

OnHierarchyInitialized();

public void Foo()
{
    // do something

    OnHierarchyInitialized(new EventArgs());

    // do something else

}

private void OnHierarchyInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler handler = HierarchyInitialized;
    handler(this, e);
}
```

Where consumers can then subscribe to the `HierarchyInitialized` event when they're interested in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely sure that the base method will never actually do anything, then an `abstract` method is exactly the right approach.  I know you say this will screw up your work of art, but think about it like this:  you want a way to explicitly tell the user that the base method does nothing.  An `abstract` method will accomplish this, whilst reminding them that the method is there, even if they choose not to use it.

Think about how interfaces work - they are a collection of abstract methods that do nothing but have to be overridden.  This is the correct approach, and compliments your work of art by enforcing the inclusion of the method.  The empty method shows the user that they can hook into the `OnHierarchyInitialized` method to achieve something.